# how to animate the levels/floors in a building that can be climbed

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I am programming a video game that looks like the cross section of a building. I need to have the player jump up through the floors and land on top of them. (kinda like in Mario bros). I have already worked out the movements of the player (currently he is just a square).

here is the JavaScript for the currant boundaries

```
// a way to bounce our player off the edges.
Player.prototype.checkEdges = function() {
    if (this.position.y > 300) {
        this.velocity.y *= 0.1;
        this.position.y = 300;
    }   else if (this.position.y < 0) {
        this.velocity.y *= -1;
        this.position.y = 0;
} 
};
```

the floors in the building are every 60 pixels.

I tried telling it that the floors were every 60 pixles (as shown)

```
 Player.prototype.checkEdges = function() {
    if (this.position.y % 60||60) > 60) {
        this.velocity.y *= 0.1;
        this.position.y = this.position.y;
    }   else if (this.position.y < 0) {
        this.velocity.y *= -1;
        this.position.y = 0;
} 
};
```

so if the player starts at the bottom I want him to be able to jump from one floor to the next. how can I do this?

p.s. (any sugestions for a new title?)

Comment: Try to narrow down the question a little bit. Instead of just dumping all the code at us, show us the relevant part only. What have you tried, and why isn't it working?

Comment: @pingul I will do that.

Comment: I just finished extracting the important code.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I would try to remove the collision checking while `velocity.y > 0` (and given that the player is jumping). Have you tried something like that?